# How to fetch data from Oracle Database using Spark SQL?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read data from some Oracle Tables (with huge volume) using Spark SQL JDBC connect. The query takes in a lot of time to complete even though it fetches only a few rows (<10). The same PL/SQL query takes 5 seconds.

Here is my code, please let me know if anything can be corrected to make it more effecient:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Init Pull") \
    .getOrCreate()

table1 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbcstring") \
    .option("dbtable", "OWNER.TABLE1") \
    .option("user", "me") \
    .option("password", "pass") \
    .option("fetchsize","100000") \
    .load()

table2 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbcstring") \
    .option("dbtable", "OWNER.TABLE2") \
    .option("user", "me") \
    .option("password", "pass") \
    .option("fetchsize","100000") \
    .load()

table3 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbcstring") \
    .option("dbtable", "OWNER.TABLE3") \
    .option("user", "me") \
    .option("password", "pass") \
    .option("fetchsize","100000") \
    .load()


table1.createOrReplaceTempView("one")
table2.createOrReplaceTempView("two")
table3.createOrReplaceTempView("three")

sqlDF = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT C.col1
                ,D.col2
                ,u.col3
        FROM one C
            LEFT JOIN two U
                ON C.colx = U.colx
                    AND C.coly = U.coly
            LEFT JOIN three D 
                ON C.colz = D.colz 
        WHERE  C.col1 = 'SomeValue'
""")

sqlDF.show(n=10)
```

Are there other better ways to read data from oracle table? I know of `cx_oracle` not sure how that compares to Spark.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `query` option to send your complete SQL to oracle, and see how fast it runs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option

Comment: I could even do the join there?

Comment: Thats the idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can try: `.option("dbtable", "(select * from OWNER.TABLE1 where rownum < 100001) TABLE1")`